# Rails is responding with wrong format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following action:

```
def something
  # do something
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I also have an `something.html.erb` template in my controller.

- When I GET /controller/something, it returns nothing.
- When I GET /controller/something.js, it renders the html with no layout.
- When I XHR GET /controller/something, it renders the html with no layout.

I would expect it to "return a template not found error" error instead of rendering the html template.

**Is this a bug of Rails or am I doing something wrong?**

- rails v3.0.4
- ruby v1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the “convention over configuration” principle. If you don't specify a `render` or `redirect_to` in the action of the controller, rails renders the view with the same name as the method. Look at [Rails render guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

Comment: But I thought that `format.js` and `params[:format] == 'js'` would instruct Rails to try and render `something.js.erb` instead of `something.html.erb`